# R data.table select rows (integer comparison)

Tags: r, data.table

When trying to select rows in a `data.table` (package for `R`) by specifying the value of a field consisting of large integers, I get strange results. Namely, similar integers are selected too.

```
require(data.table)
options(digits=15)
data <- data.table(A=c(1000200030001,1000200030002,1000200030003))
```

Try to access the first row by checking the value of A:

```
data[A==1000200030001]
               A
1: 1000200030001
2: 1000200030002
3: 1000200030003
```

All three rows are shown, where I expect only the first to be returned.

Problem solved when using `as.numeric`:

```
data[as.numeric(A)==1000200030001]
               A
1: 1000200030001
```

Problem not present in `j`part of data.table:

```
data[,A == 1000200030001]
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

This seems to be a problem with the precision of comparing large numbers. I am very confused that using `as.numeric` solves the issue since `str(data)` shows that A already is of type numeric:

```
str(data)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ A: num  1e+12 1e+12 1e+12
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
 - attr(*, "index")= atomic  
  ..- attr(*, "A")= int
```

Any hints as how to ensure this problem does not appear in (productive) code are appreciated!

UPDATE:
The problem described above is not present when disabling auto-indexing.

```
options(datatable.auto.index=FALSE)
```

However, problems with aggregation and merging/joining are not solved by disabling auto-indexing:

```
data[,.(B=sum(A)),A]
               A             B
1: 1000200030001 1000200030001
```

Where the correct output would be:

```
               A             B
1: 1000200030001 1000200030001
2: 1000200030002 1000200030002
3: 1000200030003 1000200030003
```

I found the best solution to all of these problems to use the `bit64` package as described in the selected answer. Thanks everybody!

Comment: You just have to put your condition into brackets when the `i` argument is `logical`. Try `data[(A==1000200030001)]`. The `as.numeric` part has no role, since `A` is already `numeric`.

Comment: +1 nicola. `data[,A == 1000200030001]` is logical, so if you subset data with this condition then it also works: `data[data[,A==1000200030001]]`

Comment: This might be worth a bug report. It's a problem with auto-indexing.

Comment: Regarding your edit: Use a big integer data type. That should solve all these related problems.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for your useful comments and answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `bit64::integer64`:

```
require(data.table)
options(digits=15)
library(bit64)
data <- fread("A
              1000200030001
              1000200030002
              1000200030003", colClasses = "integer64")


data[A == as.integer64("1000200030001")]
#A
#1: 1000200030001
```

Alternatively, deactivate auto-indexing (and lose the performance advantage from it):

```
options(datatable.auto.index=FALSE)
data <- data.table(A=c(1000200030001,1000200030002,1000200030003))
data[(A==1000200030001)]
#               A
#1: 1000200030001
```

Comment: While the use of `integer64` may very likely be useful for the OP's purpose, I don't think that here is *the* issue. I guess it's the known feature of `data.table` of handling the `i` argument. For the values provided in the OP, the comparison is always correct also using base operators (like `==`). Of course, these operators could be wrong for larger values.

Comment: @nicola: I call this a bug.

Comment: You are right, I didn't want to be so drastic... Anyway, once you deactivated the `auto.index`, you can remove the bracket and `data[A==1000200030001]` works (the version with the bracket used to work with the `auto.index` set to `TRUE`).

Comment: @nicola Parentheses make sure that i is evaluated, which is another way of avoiding auto-indexing.

Comment: It's not auto index that's the issue, but numeric rounding. See `?setNumericRounding`. Auto indexing is not used when expr is wrapped with `()` at the moment. Using `bit64` is the way to go.. A better warning will be issued for next release.